# How to send messages to a connected bluetooth device in iOS in the background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using BLECommander to connect to a bluetooth device in the foreground and my code is heavily based off this sample [app](http://github.com/zentri/ble_ota_ios_demo).  I believe my app would use both bluetooth-central and bluetooth-peripheral. Additionally, I would ping in the background every couple of hours to retrieve any new missing data. I am fine with connecting to a device in the foreground; I simply want to send messages to it in the background and retrieve data.

I have read the apple documentation on using core bluetooth to operate in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the apple documentation, you should know that your options are quite limited on iOS on what you can do in general when your app is in background.

However, there could be ways to achieve what you want. If you have control over the other bluetooth device you can make it change the BLE advertisement from time to time. When you scan on iOS, you will also get a scan result in background (but only once for a certain advertisement!) and can then connect to the device and read/write.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also stay connected and send BLE notification (aka a notify packet) from the peripheral device